# Client side validation not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I implemented client side validation i.e, Required `attributes` specified in `Model` and `HTML`.`ValidationMesssage` For in `.cshtml` and referenced the `JQuery` validator and was working fine when I click on `save button`. But when I implement `onClick event` of button an ajax call, the validation seems to be not working. I tried using `IsValid` but no luck.

Please find the below code.

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddClient(ClientModel clientData)
        {
            var clientObj = new Metadata.Client.Service.Client();

            string successMessage = string.Empty;

            clientObj.ClientType              = new Metadata.Client.Service.ClientType();
            clientObj.ClientName              = clientData.Client.ClientName;
            clientObj.ClientCode              = clientData.Client.ClientCode;
            clientObj.ClientType.ClientTypeId = clientData.ClientTypeSelectId;

             try
             {
                 clientObj = clientData.AddNewClient(clientObj);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {

                  return new ContentResult { Content = ex.Message, ContentType = "application/json" };

             }

             return new ContentResult { Content = successMessage, ContentType = "application/json" };
             //return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

### JQuery - Added the below references.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 $("#addForm").validate(
    {


        submitHandler: function (form) 
        {
                var clientName = $('#Client_ClientName').val();
                var clientTypeId = $('#ClientTypeSelectId').val();
                var clientCode = $('#Client_ClientCode').val();

           $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    url: "/Client/AddClient",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { "clientName": clientName, "clientTypeId": clientTypeId, "clientCode": clientCode },
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function (request) {
                        alert(request.responseText);
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        //alert('Successfully Inserted Client');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Client/ClientGrid",
                            type: 'GET',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#grid').html(data);
                                //alert('got here with data');
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                //alert('something bad happened');
                            }
                        });

                        $('#myClientDialogContainer').dialog('close');
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
```

## Model

```
   public class Client
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Client Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Client Name")]
        public string ClientName { get; set; }

        public ClientType ClientType { get; set; }
        public StatusType StatusType { get; set; }

        //[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Client Code")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Client Code")]
        public string ClientCode { get; set; }

        //[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Client Status Type Name")]
        public string ClientStatusTypeName { get; set; }

        //[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Client Status Code Name")]
        public string ClientStatusCodeName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Client Type Id")]
        public int ClientTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

## Validation code

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <span>

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Client.ClientName)
        <div class="row"></div>
        <span class ="label"> @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Client.ClientName, "Client Name :")</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Client.ClientName, new { style = "width:50%; height:20px;" })
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <span>
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ClientTypeSelectId)
             <div class="row"></div>
            <span class ="label">@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Client.ClientType.ClientTypeName, "Client Type :")</span>
             @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ClientTypeSelectId, (SelectList)ViewBag.clientTypeListCombo, " ", new { style = "width:52%" })


        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Client.ClientCode)
            <div class="row"></div>
            <span class="label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Client.ClientCode, "Client Code :")</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Client.ClientCode, new { style = "width:50%; height:20px;" })
        </span> 
    </div>
```

Please can anyone help.

Comment: I don't see any validation taking place.

Comment: $(this) in your case refers to your submit button. You need to validate your form.Also live() is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9. I would suggest using on() instead.

Comment: Your `click` handler is totally bypassing whatever you may be doing with the Validate plugin.  `ajax` should be handled inside the plugin's built-in `submitHandler` callback.

Comment: Thanks Sparky. How can I handle inside the submithandler in plugins. Any link to implement this or any example.

Comment: Hi Sparky, I modified the JQuery code and add the references JQuery validate ( Please refer my JQuery code above ), but still not working. Now when I click save without entering any details the form stays there and if I click save after entering some details than also the form stays there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of submitting your form when button is clicked, try .submit() event of your form. Wrap your input elements inside html form tag. You should serialize your form and submit it to server instead of taking input values one by one.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {

   // Prevent default submit for ajax
   e.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({ /* Your ajax stuff goes here */ });
});
```

This way you won't bypass your validation.

Comment: I implement this emre and validation is working fine. But I want to return contentresult in my error message in controller which is not coming back in ajax call. But the content result goes to a different page. As per the suggestion from Sparky I override code for Submithandler and that is also not working. Please refer my latest JQuery code in the code snippet section.